# Data type conversion problem for leetcode pratice "Moving Average from Data Stream"

Tags: java, algorithm, integer, double

When I was running the code for the leetcode question ""Moving Average from Data Stream"". I got a partly different output with the expected:
[image]
Here is my code:

```
class MovingAverage {
    
    int front = 0, rear = 0; Double sum = 0.00000;
    int[] data;

    
    public MovingAverage(int size) {
        
        data = new int[size];
        Arrays.fill(data, 0);
        
        
        
    }
    
    public double next(int val) {
        
        if(data.length == 1){
            data[rear] = val;
            return val;
        }else{
             if(rear < data.length){
             data[rear] = val;
             sum += data[rear];
             rear++;         
             return sum/rear;
                 
         }else{
             sum -= data[front];
             rear = (rear+1) % data.length - 1;
             front = (front+1) % data.length ;
             data[rear] = val;
             sum += data[rear];
             rear++;
             return sum/data.length;
         }
         
        }
        

         
    }
}
```

The requirement for code is :
[image]

When I run the tast cases of the example provided, everything is ok.
But when I run this edge case, thing is different:
["MovingAverage","next","next","next","next","next","next","next","next","next","next"]
[[5],[12009],[1965],[-940],[-8516],[-16446],[7870],[25545],[-21028],[18430],[-23464]]

Anyone can help me pls? Is my code wrong or I didn't process the data conversion well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logical check is incorrect:

```
if (rear < data.length)
```

In the corresponding `else` block, when `rear = data.length`, you set `rear = (rear+1) % data.length - 1`, so `rear < data.length` becomes true in the next iteration, and you go back to the `if` block again. However, the logic to dequeue and update values is in the `else` block (which is where you should end up once `data` is filled completely). This is why you're getting an incorrect answer; `if (rear < data.length)` isn't correct.

Replacing that condition with something like `if (numberOfElementsTillNow < data.length)` should fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found this issue by myself also.

Answer (score 0):

I revised my code, and the answer accepted:

```
class MovingAverage {

int front = 0, rear = 0; int sum = 0;
int[] data;


public MovingAverage(int size) {
    
    data = new int[size];
    Arrays.fill(data, 0);
    
    
    
}

public double next(int val) {
    
    if(data.length == 1){
        data[rear] = val;
        return (double)val;
    }else{
         if(rear < data.length){
         data[rear] = val;
         sum += (int)data[rear];
         rear++;         
         return sum * 1.0/rear;
             
     }else{
         sum -= (int)data[front % data.length];
         data[rear % data.length] = val;
         sum += (int)data[rear % data.length];
         rear++;
         front++;
         return sum * 1.0/data.length;
     }
     
    }
    

     
}
```

}

This issue can be closed.